# Multiple Documents upload in alfresco server using spring boot

Tags: amazon-s3, microservices, alfresco, rest

How to upload a folder and subfolders within documents using Alfresco Rest API ?

my folder structure is:
eductaion docs(Main folder)
(12345)Application Id(Subfolder)
--educationdocs1
--professionaldocs1
--kyc1

(784210)Application Id(subfolder)
--educationdocs2
--professionaldocs2
--kyc

Answer (score 1):

You can use alfresco bulk import feature.
https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/6.1/admin/import-transfer/